# Minimum amount of different terms matched across all queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I am searching a query across many different fields, and I want to make sure that at least 75% of the fields  are matched in total across all queries

I tried to create queries with should+minimum_should_match, terms_set+minimum_should_match and match+minimum_should_match, but it doesn't bring the results I need.

Let me use the next query as a reference (even though it doesnt work)

```
"query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": ...
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [{
                                "match": {
                                    "title": {
                                        "query": "avicii levels",
                                        "operator": "or"
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "match": {
                                    "artist": {
                                        "query": "avicii levels",
                                        "operator": "or"
                                    }
                                }
                            }],
                            
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
```

I want to return docs that match both avicii and levels, even though one of the terms will match in the title of the song and the other one in the name of the artist. I also want it to be dynamic, so it works for longer queries; for example, if you were to search "i love the way you lie eminem recovery" I want to return docs that match all (or at least a certain amount) the terms in any of the fields (title, artist, album, as I said, I query many different fields, 6 in total)

Comment: Could you please post the index mapping, ES document, and whole query?
For more detailed investigation